# LINQ query not working properly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dynamics-crm

I have MVC application and I have two entities.

Entity Lead inherits from Customer.

[image]

Now, In Lead  controllers index view,  I have written below code...

```
public ViewResult Index()

       {     

           var Leads = (from c in db.Customers.OfType<CRMEntities.Lead>()
                        where(c.IsActive == true) select c);

            return View(Leads.ToList());

        }
```

and I have the code below in the index view.

```
@model IEnumerable<CRMEntities.Lead>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>
.
.
```

Records exist in the table it not returning any record.
Is query right?

Full View Code

```
@model PagedList.IPagedList<CRMEntities.Lead>


@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            Status
        </th>
        <th>
            IsQualified
        </th>
        <th>
            Name
        </th>
        <th>
            Address
        </th>
        <th>
            OfficePhone1
        </th>
        <th>
            Website
        </th>
        <th>
            Email2
        </th>
        <th>
            Email1
        </th>
        <th>
            FaxNo
        </th>
        <th>
            Remark
        </th>
        <th>
            Rating
        </th>
        <th>
            BusinessType
        </th>
        <th>
            IsActive
        </th>

    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Status)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.IsQualified)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Address)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.OfficePhone1)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Website)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Email2)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Email1)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FaxNo)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Remark)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Rating)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.BusinessType)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.IsActive)
        </td>

        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.Id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.Id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.Id })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Query looks fine from what can be seen.

The view code you are showing will not display anything.  Write out @Model.Count() in the view to see how many records you have.

If you don't have a database profiler, I'd recommend getting one.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I have updated my question. I have added full view code. Please check.

Comment: view seems good.  can you write a integration test to verify that you get results back for that query?  or put a break point in Index view to see what is being returned.  Now it looks like there are simply no leads.